# Android background service get window.localStorage from phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, android-service

I need a backgorund service on phonegap, but i didn't find any way on phonegap. I decided to use a android background service. But i dont know how to communicate with phonegap. I need `window.localStorage` data (it is login information), how?

Answer (score 1):

I am currently testing PhoneGap. And I have many issues.
GPS : watchPosition() doesn't work coorectly
Photo : Strange system (0_o)
and many other like :

Services : if you want services, you have to develop a plugins for all platforms. But what is the adavantage of a "crossplatform" technology if you have to develop in native for all platforms via plugins. Nothing.

Try it in Native Android ! Especially if your future app will be only in Android.

Comment: And I just some very bad problem in Cordova like :RequestUpdateLocation set at ONE MINUTE !!!!! And you can't modify this in JS/Cordova. You have to open the Android Project with......Eclipse....